# Highest consecutive number in sorted set

Tags: c#, sortedset

I have a `SortedSet<int>` of integers and numbers are added to it in random order. 
For e.g  `1, 2, 4, 0, 3`

How can I find the highest consecutive integer in the set starting from `0`?

for e.g 
if the set contains `{1,2,4}`, the result should be `0`

for `{0,1,2}`, the result should be `2`

and so on

I did try `SortedSet.Max` but that gives me the maximum value in the set, not the highest consecutive one.

Comment: Please, show us your code

Comment: Along with the problem you should **include the code you have up until this point** (*make some effort to answer your problem/question as [so] is not a code writing service*). After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Writing the Perfect Question*](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `Max()` since it will return maximum value in set (as you've already noticed).

Example solution with poor performance and probably buggy but you get the idea:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //SortedSet will sort elements on its own (since its Sorted...), so we can throw elements at it at random (as in requirements)
            var mySet = new SortedSet<int> { -7, -6, -4, -2, -3, -5, -1, 1, 2, 5, 7, 8, 9, 4, 13, 12, 11, 14, 15 };
            var yourSet = new SortedSet<int> { 1, 2, 4, 0, 3 };

            int mySetCount = CalculateConsecutiveOccurrenceCount(mySet);
            int yourSetCount = CalculateConsecutiveOccurrenceCount(yourSet);

            Console.WriteLine($"My set: {mySetCount}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Your set: {yourSetCount}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static int CalculateConsecutiveOccurrenceCount(SortedSet<int> sortedSet)
        {
            var largestCount = 0;
            var consecutiveOccurrenceCount = 0;
            var lastRead = (int?)null;
            var valuesRead = 0;

            using (var enumerator = sortedSet.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    valuesRead++;

                    //First item
                    if (!lastRead.HasValue)
                    {
                        lastRead = enumerator.Current;
                        continue;
                    }


                    //Consecutive occurrence
                    if (enumerator.Current - lastRead == 1)
                    {
                        consecutiveOccurrenceCount++;
                    }
                    //Consecutive occurrence reset
                    else
                    {
                        //Was it largest consecutive occurence?
                        if (consecutiveOccurrenceCount > largestCount)
                        {
                            //Update then
                            largestCount = consecutiveOccurrenceCount;
                        }

                        //Reset
                        consecutiveOccurrenceCount = 0;
                    }

                    //For last element in enumerable and still have consecutive occurrence - check, if we don't have to update largestCount
                    if (valuesRead == sortedSet.Count)
                    {
                        if (consecutiveOccurrenceCount > largestCount)
                        {
                            largestCount = consecutiveOccurrenceCount;
                        }
                    }

                    lastRead = enumerator.Current;
                }
            }

            return largestCount;
        }
    }
```

Also, I guess `{1,2,4}` should yield `result == 1`, since we have one consecutive occurrence: 1->2.